# Can I host Windows Forms control in a Windows Store app?

Tags: winforms, windows-store

I want to create Windows Store app and it in it would like to host some Windows Forms controls. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot do it.

Comment: why would you want to do that? Windows Store apps are XAML-enabled. You can do much better UIs than with winforms.

Comment: Reasons are irrelevant, it is just a case I wanted to deal with. One can host WinForms control in WPF app, but not in Windows store app?

Comment: @checho Windows Store apps are based on current technology. See "Windows Runtime", most XAML-based concepts are implemented there because they're actually useful, but no one really cares about useless winforms, that's why current technologies have no support for it whatsoever. If you have (properly MVVM-capable) WPF UIs, you can relatively easily port them over to WinRT. If you have winforms stuff, you're stuck in winforms forever, unless you do a complete rewrite.

Comment: @HighCore there are still many controls GDI+ controls which can't be rewritten for WPF/WS apps. I battle with some of these legacies as well (e.g. ActiveX controls for rendering video). So, any clue on how to do this?

Comment: @AndreiFloroiu use a `MediaElement`. Other than that, I can't imagine a single case where archaic winforms functionality can't be achieved with a couple of lines of XAML in current technologies.

Comment: @HighCore MediaElement is good for video that uses standard codecs (even those that come with K-Lite Mega Codec Pack). When you deal with recording devices (NVRs, DVRs, etc.) you either save time and use vendor control (ActiveX and/or WinForms/GDI+), or you die writing Media Foundation Filters for their H.264 custom implementations which may differ from firmware version to another. Don't have the time/budget to do their work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. As pointed out in the comments, Windows Store apps use XAML and not winforms, and also run inside an app container (Modern UI) and cannot access the desktop (where winforms works). Also, Windows Store apps run in a highly sandboxed environment and cannot run external desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question may have been "no" in the past, but it appears that Microsoft has a specific solution to address this scenario. the Desktop to UWP Bridge is designed to host Windows Forms and legacy applications in a UWP container that can (with some limitations) be installed from the Windows Store.

The Desktop to UWP Bridge appears to be designed to handle this situation

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop